# Where to put my professional (academic) personal page after my PhD

Tags: website

I am a PhD student, and the defense of my thesis is at the end of this year.
During my PhD, I had an institution server account to put my page.
However, it is closed (I finished my PhD longer than the expected time).

Although it looks like difficult, I still want to try to obtain post-doc position.
During several months (or even one year) after I graduate, I don't know where
to put my personal/professional page, which should be good for applying the job.

I found there are some personal website provider (e.g. wix.com), however
after a quick look on the templates, the styles not seem very academic professional.

Do you have any idea what should I do to create my page during this time?

Answer (score 2):

Buy your own domain name and host your own website. You can design your own website, download a free template, or commission your own website.

Comment: I am not familiar with these things. May you give some (more details of) advantages of buying domain name over the free web hosting?

Comment: Longevity, control, SEO, ...

Comment: (You can google for more.)